# Why is my velocity decaying?

Tags: java, physics, euler-method

Programming in Java.  Tinkering around with physics.  My entities all have position and velocity.  In the main loop, all I'm doing is applying gravity and bouncing off the edges, like so:

```
    //  add gravity vector
    o.velocity.add(GRAVITY.cpy().mul(dt));

    //  bounce off walls
    if ((o.position.x<0 && o.velocity.x<0) || (o.position.x>WORLD_SIZE_X && o.velocity.x>0))
        o.velocity.x*=-1;

    //  bounce off of ground
    if (o.position.y<=0.0f) {
        o.position.y=0.0f;
        if (o.velocity.y<0)
            o.velocity.y *= -1;
    }
```

The x and y values of my vectors are just floats.

For the first second it looks like it's working fine, but the vertical velocities slowly decay.  Any idea why?

Comment: When you say the vertical velocities "slowly decay", do you mean that they fall downward or that the velocity decreases with time, or what?

Comment: GRAVITY.cpy().mul(dt) is just multiplying time by the gravity vector and adding it to the velocity vector, right? Are you sure that's what it's doing? (That's a weird way of writing `z.velocity += Gravity * dt;`, for Java code.)

Comment: By the way, is it your intention to allow the velocity to continue to press against a wall? If not, you should be flipping velocity in the same way that you do when you bounce off the ground.

Comment: By decay I mean it bounces just like a real ball, eventually stopping bouncing.  It's actually a nice effect, but unintended so it's bothering me!  :-)  The reason I'm writing GRAVITY.cpy().mul(dt) is because I'm using simple 2d vector objects with adding/multiplying built in, so I can't just do v1 = v1 + v2

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "continue to press against a wall"??

Comment: The velocity can stay pointing toward a wall, after you've stopped the zombie from moving through it.

Comment: "so I can't just do v1 = v1 + v2", Of course you can just do `v1 = v1 + v2`. You can do it with integers cant you? Floats? You just overload the addition operator, and then you can do that. You can do this with your own custom integer class too, or whatever other object you want to have.

Comment: My intent is for them to bounce off and go the other direction - that's why I'm multiplying x velocity by -1;  Should I be doing that differently?

Comment: Okay, I understand your problem, and have an answer for you now :) One moment while I write it.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify - I'm using a Vector2d class which is provided by a library I'm using (libgdx).  I don't know if it's overloaded in that library.

Comment: (waiting patiently)  :-D

Comment: @Olhovsky Java doesn't support operator overloading: vector maths in Java really is that ugly.

Comment: @PeterT: !!! Oh...

Comment: It might also be noted that even if it did support operator overloading, it would tend to lead to a lot of garbage, particularly in things like physics, since all vectors etc need to be full blown Objects. It tends to be a good idea to reuse vectors in Java - leading to still more ugliness in the code.  It is a good language and technology in other ways though and the tools are great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As long as you only apply **constant acceleration** (i.e. from constant gravity) **Eulers Method is accurate** and the ball must bounce forever, reaching its initial position again after each bounce phase. If not, then there is something wrong with the implementation of Euler's Method. Here is how it should look like:

```
void update(float dt)
{
    position += velocity * dt + acceleration * 0.5 * dt * dt;
    velocity += acceleration * dt;
    // handling only the simple ground collision case here
    if(position.x < radius)
    {
        velocity = -velocity;
    }        
}
```

Note the acceleration is constant here, its simply the gravity.

**EDIT:**

It seems both, the [article on gaffergames](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/integration-basics/) and the code in the question use a simpler form of Euler's Method, namely:

```
     position += velocity * dt;
     velocity += acceleration * dt;
```

whereas this one as also shown in this [paper](http://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/sg/AM35odes.pdf):

```
     position += velocity * dt + acceleration * 0.5 * dt * dt;
     velocity += acceleration * dt;
```

is still capable of correctly integratiing constant accelerations.

Note: This answer is not supposed to mean that the Euler Method is a good choice for complex physics and non-constant accelerations, nor that you should stick to it once you want to add more physics dynamics to your scene. However, if the application will only use constant acceleration, then this method perfectly fits your needs.

Comment: I don't think that it's accurate for constant accelleration. Read the link I gave in my answer: http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/integration-basics/

Comment: +1, using your integration into position, that seems to work out with constant accelleration **and constant timestep**.

Comment: @Olhovsky:  I'm still confused.  From the article:  "Euler integration is the most basic of numerical integration techniques. It is only 100% accurate if the rate of change is constant over the timestep."  Isn't my rate of change here constant, since I never change my gravity?

Comment: @loneboat yes, the rate of change of the velocity, but not the rate of change of the position, as he explains in the next sentence

Comment: @loneboat @Olhovsky this [paper](http://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/sg/AM35odes.pdf) also says the correct Euler Method implementation is `pos(t+dt) = pos(t) + dt*v(t) + 0.5*dt*dt*a(t)` and not just `pos(t+dt) = pos(t) + dt*v(t)' which basically says the gaffa side and you used the wrong Euler Method, which at least is correct for constant acceleration

Comment: @Maik:  Awesome.  Thanks so much for your answers!

Comment: My pleasure, you're very welcome @loneboat

Comment: Note that this can be rewritten with fewer multiplications: `float newvelocity = velocity + acceleration * dt; position += 0.5 * (velocity + newvelocity) * dt; velocity = newvelocity;`

Answer (score 5):

Your objects are bouncing with subsequently smaller bounces because you are applying basic newtonian physics rules to your objects, so they mimic behavior of such objects as you'd expect them to in real life.

You are constantly applying gravity to the velocity of the objects.

When you flip the direction of velocity, the object is now moving up, with an upward velocity, but you are removing some of this velocity with a downward gravity velocity application. With perfect elasticity, and zero friction, you'd expect the object to reach the previous height, but...

You are using [Euler integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) to approximate the integration of force. This approximation underestimates the effect of the force application.

So when your object hits the ground and velocity is flipped, it can't reach as high as it was before, because the application of gravity is not perfectly accurately integrated (it would be if you had an infintesimally small timestep).

Read "Why Euler's is never good enough":
http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/integration-basics/

I think that Euler's actually **is** often good enough, but that's another matter...

Comment: Hmmm, but even with Newtonian physics, there isn't any explicit decay in motion.  If a rubber ball were to bounce with perfect efficiency (nothing lost to heat or rotation), wouldn't it bounce forever?  Since I'm just flipping the vector, I would expect it to be a "perfect" bounce, and it should bounce all the way back up to its initial height before dropping again.

Comment: You are using Euler integration over a finite timestep. It's not that accurate.

Comment: I will elaborate, one moment.

Comment: Reading this now (found it by the keywords you mentioned) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769466/physics-why-is-verlet-integration-better-than-euler-integration/2770564#2770564

Comment: I started writing a detailed explanation, but I decided to give you a link instead.

Comment: The SO question you linked to is okay, but the link I gave makes it pretty clear, if you read the section that I mentioned.

Comment: Basically, if you add velocity a bunch of times, you wind up underestimating the actual position difference, with a closer approximation if more steps are used.

Comment: Awesome, thanks - appreciate the time!  I'll go ahead and mark this as answered until I'm more smarter about Euler and Verlet!  Thanks again.

Comment: You don't want to overestimate though, because then you'd be adding energy to your simulation, and the zombies would bounce away into space (or start flying around off all the walls).

Comment: If you want to solve the problem, there are a few things that come to mind, without having to implement verlet or some other integration technique.

Comment: Verlet is also just an approximation, and also underestimates (it's just more accurate).

Comment: Do you want the zombies to bounce forever, or just bounce more? You could try adding a percentage to your velocity when you flip it, but first check if the velocity is high enough (implement some threshold value that prevents adding velocity always). That would make them bounce higher and longer.

Comment: If you want your zombies to just bounce forever, then maybe just use add an offset using a cos() function on the y position of the zombies?

Comment: No, I actually eventually wanted them to do exactly what they're doing now, but with an explicit decay specified by myself, not some arbitrary integration error. :-\  So it's doing what I want for now, I just didn't expect it because I was expecting it to behave like a classical newtonian system.

Comment: I was expecting to have to add the effect in myself, and was just disconcerted when it happened by way of error.

Comment: Oh! Okay, that's good. Well now you know why then :) Imperfect elasticity would cause them to bounce less anyway. I'm usually okay with euler integration.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  I'm going to have to read the article you mentioned tomorrow, since I've been staring at this long enough that I'm turning into a bit of a zombie myself!  For now I'm off to bed.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @loneboat @Olhovsky as long as you apply constant acceleration (i. e. grvaity), Euler's method works perfectly and your ball should bounce for ever, see my answer

Comment: Maik: I don't think so, see the link in my answer which uses constant accelleration as an example.

Comment: @Olhovsky Interesting, he uses `position += velocity * dt;` whereas `position += velocity * dt + acceleration * 0.5 * dt * dt;` as in my code example gives the correct answer for constant acceleration, using his example, that integrator ends exactly at 500 meters after 10 sec. Now I wonder which one is the Euler Method. I didn't manage to find a proper link after some searching.

Comment: @Olhovsky Would you mind talk in the chat about it? I'm very intereested in that matter, because when I use the latter integration the ball bounces happily for hours, always properly back to its initial position.

Comment: Hmm, that does seem to work out, and that does seem to still be euler integration (I think). I guess the answer for loneboat for now, is to try your method and see if it works :)

Comment: He'll also need to fix his timestep though, which is something that he probably wants to do for a physics simulation anyway.

Comment: That's the confusing part, it really works out, the example at gaffer and also my test app, I had a ball bouncing for hours on my screen, though it seems it's not eulers method. I think I just found something to dig deeper into :)

Comment: Ah, there is a http://physics.stackexchange.com, I think I will try it there, thx @Olhovsky :)

Comment: I don't think your question will be recieved well there. I've tried asking there about simulating physics before -- they don't like that. They consider it a programming problem, not a physics theory problem. In fact, my question was moved to gamedev.

Answer (score 2):

Olhovsky explains the problem, but he left out the simple fix. Apply gravity twice.

Basically you are doing three things over and over.

Gravity
Collision
Movement

Swap the order of any two and you'd actually get the opposite problem. Do a halfway swap and you are even. In practice that means do half the gravity before collision checks, and half the gravity after.

½ Gravity
Collision
½ Gravity
Movement